# Performing background tasks in asp.net MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in asp.net MVC4. and I m building an online shopping store. I am providing user an option to upload a file containing thousands of records to upload in a file and then my application will store them in database system. It's a long task. So I want to do this task in background. when user upload a file containing bulk of records. then user should be allowed to do some other task. And adding records should be done in background. Please tell me how should I proceed. any helping material, tutorial? Moreover I 'm not using Entity framework. I'm using simple connection oriented model. I have seenn on many posts on stackoverflow but could not find solution to my task
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in your controller, but AFAIK it does not guarantee that your thread will not be aborted by app pool recycling.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        //do something here with your Request.Files[0].InputStream;
    },
    CancellationToken.None,
    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, // guarantees separate thread
    TaskScheduler.Default);
```

UPD:

Reliable way would be to save a file, and have Windows Service process it in background.